# Manually changing colors of nodes in process_map

Tags: r, bupar

I am building process maps looking at individual patients (one map per patient).  I would like to color code my events based on the type of event, something like scale_fill_manual in ggplot2 :

```
custom_color <- c("Registration" = "#c7e8ac", "Triage and Assessment" = "#b391b5", "Blood test" = "#3aa6dd")

event_data_test %>%
  process_map(performance( ))
```

I am trying to figure out how to integrate my custom_color- is this possible?

I see that I can use a color scale, but I need to use a set of colors that aren't a scale (and need to be the same across several maps)